# Get all inactive users on Amplitude

Tags: amplitude-analytics

Using the `amplitude API` how can I get all users (and their `amplitude_id`) that have not been active in the last N days? I see that the user has the `lastSeen` property but it's not clear to me how to filter on it.

For example I thought maybe `'https://amplitude.com/api/2/usersearch?user=*&matches={"last_seen": "2019-01-18"}'` might be along the right lines, with some modification to get `last_seen` less than some date, but seems not to work.

There is a more complex query set, but `last_seen` doesn't seem to be a valid property on it: https://amplitude.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205469748-Dashboard-Rest-API-Export-Amplitude-Dashboard-Data#query-parameters

Comment: last_seen is not part of standard user properties rather a custom one meaning that if you look at dash API example, you should be able to call it with gb:last_seen